# Who is a message receiver in ios?

Tags: ios

Is a message receiver is an object? Is it a methods? Is it a class?

Why is the term  **receiver** used in iOS?

Comment: Are you asking about the message sending(calling method) mechanism in iOS?

Comment: You should get your terminology straight for starters. iOS is an operating system. Objective-C is a programming language that uses message passing. This topic is covered very amply in the Apple docs and no doubt here as well.